# LDAP Connection Timeout Error(OpenLDAP with Backend MySQL)

Tags: mysql, openldap

all

I tried to connect to OpenLDAP with Backend MySQL.

It does not work fine when I try to access to OpenLDAP with more than 5 ldap queries per second.LDAP Connection Timeout Error occurred frequently.

My detail environment is as below.

- OS
  CentOS release 6.10 (Final)
- mysql-connector-odbc
  mysql-connector-odbc-5.1.5r1144-7.el6.x86_64
- unixODBC
  unixODBC-2.2.14-14.el6.x86_64
- odbcinst.ini

```
[MySQL]  
Description     = ODBC for MySQL  
Driver          = /usr/lib/libmyodbc5.so  
Setup           = /usr/lib/libodbcmyS.so  
Driver64        = /usr/lib64/libmyodbc5.so  
Setup64         = /usr/lib64/libodbcmyS.so  
FileUsage       = 1
```

- openLDAP

```
# rpm -qa | grep openldap
openldap-clients-2.4.40-16.el6.x86_64
openldap-2.4.40-16.el6.x86_64
openldap-servers-2.4.40-16.el6.x86_64
openldap-servers-sql-2.4.40-16.el6.x86_64
```

- Backend mysql
  MySQL 5.6.34